# How to hold values in a CDI conversion scope?

Tags: jsf, cdi, jsf-2.2

I try to add a object to a `LinkedList` in a `@ConversationScoped` backing bean.

```
@Named
@ConversationScoped
public class CategoryController implements Serializable{
...
    private List<Category> selectedCategories = new LinkedList<Category>();
...
    @PostConstruct
    public void initNewMember() {
        conversation.begin();
        newCategory = new Category();
        loadExistingCategories();
    }
...
}
```

I want to send an ajax request with new objects (of type category). They should simply be added to the linked list.

```
this.selectedCategories.add(newParentCategory);
```

With the ajax render attribute `<f:ajax render="allSelectedCategories"/>` I immediately render the output text to render the object list.

```
<h:outputText id="allSelectedCategories" value="#{categoryController.selectedCategories}" />
```

And yes, the object I clicked is displayed, but the previously clicked objects are gone.

The values do not serialize/persist in memory during my "conversation". What do I need to do to make that conversion scope temporarily persist the values of the ajax calls?

I really want to get used to CDI and abandon the ManagedBean path for this project (e.g. `@ViewScoped`), despite the fact that it works like a charm.

---

Also, I cannot reproduce the following [tutorial](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/java-ee-cdi-conversationscoped-example) on CDI Conversation Scope. I simply cannot debug into the `initConversation` by adding

```
<f:event listener="#{categoryController.initConversation}"
        type="preRenderView"></f:event>
```

Comment: What is the id of your conversation? Does it stay the same over all requests?

Comment: @Kukeltje The idea is to hold the variables while adding and removing new categories, respectively sending AJAX requests to the server. What do you mean with "it"?

Comment: I'm missing the point. I did not assign any ID. I think I need to read up on that if you push me this way.